# PowerBI Additive Slicers (Applied to whole Report)

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, filtering, dax

I have a quite niche problem in regards to PowerBI slicer operations.

I wish to filter the data based on  two different slicers.

For example I have two different slicers;

1. A list of categories, say Genre of Films; and
2. A list of all film directors

I wish to filter the data shown in the PowerBI report based on an OR condition between the two slicers.

For instance, I wish to filter based on all *Horror* films OR films directed by *Quentin Tarantino*. So this list would show all Horror films in my database and all films directed by Quentin Tarantino (that are not necessarily Horror films).

I presume that I will need to write some form of DAX code for this but through substantive searching I have not come across this particular problem.

Let me know if you need any further info.

Regards,
**Josh**

Comment: try this article:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-or-conditions-between-slicers-in-dax/

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a table called IMDB like following

```
|                       tbl-IMDB                            |
|--------------------------|---------|----------------------|
| Name                     | Genre   | Director             |
|--------------------------|---------|----------------------|
| The Shawshank Redemption | Drama   | Frank Darabont       |
| The Godfather            | Crime   | Francis Ford Coppola |
| The Dark Knight          | Action  | Christopher Nolan    |
| 12 Angry Men             | Drama   | Sidney Lumet         |
| Schindler's List         | History | Steven Spielberg     |
| Pulp Fiction             | Crime   | Quentin Tarantino    |
```

and  two more disconnected table for slicers as following

```
|     tbl-Director     |
|----------------------|
| Director             |
|----------------------|
| Frank Darabont       |
| Francis Ford Coppola |
| Christopher Nolan    |
| Sidney Lumet         |
| Steven Spielberg     |
| Quentin Tarantino    |

|tbl-Genre|
|---------|
| Genre   |
|---------|
| Drama   |
| Crime   |
| Action  |
| History |
```

the data model looks like this
[image: DataModel]

Now, if I understood your question correctly, when you select {Crime,Action} from Genre and {Sidney Lumet, Steven Spielberg} from Director it should return 5 instances; i.e. leaving only the first instance of -The Shawshank Redemption

In order to get there, first all the slicer combinations are needed to be taken into account and what they can do the table.

**a. all the slicer values are selected in Director and Genre slicer** - DAX to return the full table.

**b. none of the slicer values are selected in Director and Genre slicer** - DAX to return the full table *because the default behavior of DAX is to return the full table if nothing is selected in the slicer*.

**c. partial values are selected in Genere and nothing/everything is selected in Director and vice versa** -
*DAX is to return the full table* for example, if Drama is selected (2 instances) + nothing/everything is selected in Director (6 instnaces) -> total 6 instances

**d. partial values are selected in both Genere and Director** - *DAX to return the addition of  the instances according to the slicer selection* - ;e,g. Drama=2+Sideney Lumet=1 => total 3 instances

The above logic can be incorporated in a DAX measure like following

```
Measure = 
VAR _genre =  --- what are the genres selected from Genere Slicer and find them in IMDB tbl
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( IMDB, IMDB[Genre] IN ALLSELECTED ( Genre[Genre] ) ), 
        IMDB[Genre]
    )
VAR _director = --- what are the directors selected from Director Slicer and find them in IMDB tbl
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( IMDB, IMDB[Director] IN ALLSELECTED ( Director[Director] ) ),
        IMDB[Director]
    )
VAR _genreCountALL =  -- what are the total count of genere from Genre tbl regardless of the slicer seletion
    CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Genre[Genre] ), ALL ( Genre ) )
VAR _directorCountALL = -- what are the total count of director from Director tbl regardless of the slicer seletion
    CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Director[Director] ), ALL ( Director ) )
VAR _genreCountSELECT = -- what are the total count of genere from Genre tbl according to slicer seletion
    COUNT ( Genre[Genre] )
VAR _directorCountSELECT = -- what are the total count of director from Director tbl according to slicer seletion
    COUNT ( Director[Director] )
VAR _slice = --- if Genere and/Director slicer are both selected then return the max else in every other instances it is a full tbl
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        _genreCountALL <> _genreCountSELECT
            && _directorCountALL <> _directorCountSELECT,
            CALCULATE (
                MAX ( IMDB[Name] ),
                FILTER ( IMDB, IMDB[Director] IN { _director } || IMDB[Genre] IN { _genre } )
            ),
        CALCULATE ( MAX ( IMDB[Name] ) )
    )
RETURN
    _slice
```

and put a visual level filter like following
[image: s0]

The measure produces following

**`nothing is selected - returns full table`**
[image: S1]

**`partial values are selected in only one slicer- returns full table`**
[image: S2]

**`partial values are selected in all available slicers - returns the sliced table`**

[image: S3]